# Rocket > BlueZone > EMReadScreen api Method not storing value in Buffer variable

Tags: ruby, win32ole

Trying to read value from Bluezone screen in RUBY lang using EMReadScreen method provided by BlueZone software. But this method doesnt return value in the Buffer string. It works fine in VB script but in Ruby.

Link to API doc - https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/bluezone/help/v71/en/bzsh/default.htm#%2Fbluezone%2Fhelp%2Fv71%2Fen%2Fbzsh%2Fbzaa_aref_EMReadScreen.htm

Code :

```
require 'win32ole'

class Dummy

  @system = WIN32OLE.new('BlueZone.System')
  sleep 2
  sessions = @system.Sessions
  sleep 2
  session = sessions.Open('path')
  sleep 2
  @system.WriteScreen("enter_screen", 18,40 ) # This one is working
  sleep 4
  @system.ReadScreen(@buffer_variable,05,18,40 ) # This line doesnt throw any error but buffer_varailble not storing any value.
  sleep 2
  puts @buffer_variable  # returns nothing, expecting to store "enter"
end
```

Comment: okay, and what does it return if it doesn't return a value in the Buffer string? where is `@buffer_variable` defined? what is `@buffer_variable.class`? `@buffer_variable.inspect`? if it's not defined anywhere, what happens if you `@buffer_variable = @system.ReadScreen(05,18,40 )`

Comment: Hi Josh,
Instance variable so didn't define it. Even tried defining first then using. Still no luck.

Comment: Even tried defining first then using. Still no luck. Tried all .class, .inspect stuff but they just return nilclass, nil, string (if defined).

Answer (score 2):

Some BlueZone functions require you to initialize variables before using them.  Try setting @buffer_variable to a blank string before calling ReadScreen:

```
  sleep 4
  @buffer_variable = ""
  @system.ReadScreen(@buffer_variable,05,18,40 )
```